# javascript image problem

Tags: javascript

how cand i add a value to the class element in an image?

for src and align it works, and it adds the values to src and align:

```
src : this.inputs['src'].value,
align : this.inputs['align'].value,
```

but when i write class it becomes highlighted and it dosen't add the value to the class element in the images html:

```
class: this.inputs['class'].value,
```

is 'class' a reserved word in javascript? if yes is there another solution for my prolem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words .reserved as future keyword by the ECMAScript specification:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` **is** a reserved word.

You can still use reserved words as member names in objects by quoting them:

```
{
    'class': 'foo'
}
```

Regardless, the `class` attribute is actually set via `className` in JavaScript:

```
{
    src: 'foo.jpg',
    align: 'left',
    className: 'something'
}
```

Bear in mind that setting this will overwrite any existing classes you have defined: to combat this you can simply append the new class to the existing value:

```
this.className += ' another class';
```

To **replace** an existing class you can do:

```
this.className = (" " + this.className + " ").replace(' yourOldClass ','  yourNewClass ');
```